# Lumen 5.5 all requests are going through auth

Tags: lumen-5.5

My routes in web.php are as below:

```
$router->post('apiToken', 'AuthController@getApiToken');

$router->group(['middleware' => 'auth:api'], function () use ($router) {
    $router->get('users', 'UserController@index');
    $router->post('users', 'UserController@store');
    $router->get('users/{id}', 'UserController@show');
    $router->put('users/{id}', 'UserController@update');
    $router->delete('users/{id}', 'UserController@destroy');
});
```

When I access the route 'apiToken', it hits the AuthServiceProvider@viaRequest first.  I don't understand why?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  I was injecting a repository inside AuthController which was having \Auth::user() in the constructor.  So \Auth::user() triggers the whole authenticate mechanism whether your route is using the Auth middleware or not.  Hope it helps someone.